# Autohotkey, remap Left Alt + Space to Control + Escape

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to use Autohotkey to make the Windows start menu appear by pressing <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> instead of <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Escape</kbd> on a keyboard that doesn't have any Windows key.

I'm not sure how you do that. This is what I have tried:

```
!Space::LWin
!Space::SendInput {LWin}
!Space::Send {Ctrl}{click}
!Space::Send {Ctrl}{Escape}
!Space::SendInput, {^Escape}
!Space::ControlClick, x0 y1200
!Space::MouseClick, left, 0, 1200
!Space::Click, 0, %A_ScreenHeight%
!Space::send {sc05b}
!Space::send {vk5Bsc15B}
```

But I can't get it to work. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
!Space::Send ^{Esc}
```