# Adding Alt + Space shortcut in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, shortcut, space, alt

I am using `win7` and `eclipse` with Aptana plugin for trying some examples on Ruby. But I can't figure out how to add <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> as a shortcut in Eclipse (I want to add it to complete already defined variables). The issue is that when I try to add that combination (Eclipse reads the keys clicked) and the menu window appears in the top left -> it is shown when you hit the Alt key.

Does anyone has a hint how to add the shortcut?

I found similar post, but don't know how and where to add the code there.
[Autohotkey, remap Left Alt + Space to Control + Escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371730/autohotkey-remap-left-alt-space-to-control-escape)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eclipse, the code-completion shortcut is Ctrl+Space (it's called Content Assist in Eclipse lingo). Is that what you're looking for?
I'm pretty sure it can be mapped to a different keyboard combination. Open Preferences and navigate to General > Keys and then search for the Content Assist command to re-map.